# How do you specify the ca cert when connecting to RDS via R Postgres?

Tags: r, postgresql

```
    #https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgres/README.html

    library(DBI)
    # Connect to a specific postgres database i.e. Heroku
    con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),dbname = 'DATABASE_NAME', 
                     host = 'HOST', # i.e. 'ec2-54-83-201-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
                     port = 5432, # or any other port specified by your DBA
                     user = 'USERNAME',
                     password = 'PASSWORD')
```

Trying to connect to the DB, but I get a ssl verification error because the remote DB is Aurora.  is there a parameter to pass the SSL CA root?

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
rt_cert <- paste0("PATH_OF_ROOT_CERTIFICATE/root-ca.crt")
cl_cert <- paste0("PATH_OF_ROOT_CERTIFICATE/xxx.crt")
cl_key <- paste0("PATH_OF_ROOT_CERTIFICATE/xxx.key")

con <- dbConnect(drv = RPostgres::Postgres(), 
                 dbname = 'DATABASE_NAME', 
                 host = 'HOST', # i.e. 'ec2-54-83-201-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
                 port = 5432, # or any other port specified by your DBA
                 user = 'USERNAME',
                 password = 'PASSWORD',
                 sslmode = 'require',
                 sslrootcert = rt_cert,
                 sslcert = cl_cert,
                 sslkey = cl_key)
```